# Split array of string with multiple delimiters and store in separate arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I have a Javascript object like

```
Object = { "ratio1" : "12+45*36",
                 "ratio2" : "34+45*16",
                  "ratio3" : "17+25"}
```

I am trying to split the values like the values before + in one array and values after + in one array . so the output should be like

```
Array1= ["12" , "34" , "17"]
Array2 = ["45" , "36" , "45","16","25"].
```

To perform this I am iterating through the keys and getting the values first then I am again iterating through the values array I am splitting it using

```
ratioArray.split("+");
```

This gave me [[" 12" , "45*36"], [" 34", "45*16"], [" 17", "25"]]

Now again I have iterate through all the three arrays and split using second delimiter. Is there any efficient way to perform this so that I can reduce these many iterations

Comment: It's the right way..

Comment: Actually I am stuck here . I am unable to perform the split with the resultant array :(

Comment: `str.split(/[+*]/)`

Answer (score 1):

```js
const ratios = {
  "ratio1" : "12+45*36",
  "ratio2" : "34+45*16",
  "ratio3" : "17+25"
}


const nums = Object.keys(ratios)
  .map(key => ratios[key]
    .replace(/[+*]/g, '|')
    .split('|')
  )

const [ array1, array2, array3 ] = nums

document.querySelector('pre').innerText = 
  `array1 === [${array1}]\n` +
  `array2 === [${array2}]\n` +
  `array2 === [${array3}]\n`
```

```html
<pre />
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var Object = {
    "ratio1": "12+45*36",
    "ratio2": "34+45*16",
    "ratio3": "17+25"
}

var Array1 = [],
    Array2 = [],
    temp;
for (var key in Object) {
    temp = Object[key].split('+');
    Array1.push(temp[0])
    temp = temp[1].split('*')
    for(var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++){
      Array2.push(temp[i])
    }
}

console.log('Array1:['+Array1[0]+','+Array1[1]+','+Array1[2]+']')
console.log('Array2:['+Array2[0]+','+Array2[1]+','+Array2[2]+','+Array2[3]+','+Array2[4]+']')
```

Comment: This is working like a charm . thank you so much . can you help me to make the final merging to single array as dynamic .

Comment: @Karthi what do you mean? explain

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```js
object = {
  "ratio1": "12+45*36",
  "ratio2": "34+45*16",
  "ratio3": "17+25"
}

var array1 = [],
  array2 = [];

for (var key in object) {

  var _o = object[key].split("+");
  array1.push(_o[0]);

  _o[1].split("*").forEach(function(num) {
    array2.push(num);
  })

};

console.log("array 1", array1);
console.log("array 2", array2)
```